# java why is this thread executed twice before sleeping?

Tags: java

I am writing a 2d game at the moment to learn java, and i use a thread as a counter to animate the player (it increases an integer, which tells the paintComponent method which picture to paint). But for some reason the thread is executed twice before it sleeps. The relevant thread is the shipanimation thread.

```
public class Frame extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
    public static Frame frame;
private JPanel contentPane;
RenderPanel panel;
public Ship ship = new Ship(36, 72);
int y = 0;
int time;
int animation = 0;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                frame = new Frame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Frame() {
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel = new RenderPanel();
    setBounds(100, 100, 256*3, 276*3);
    ship.setPos((this.getWidth()/2), (this.getHeight()/4)*3);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    Thread backgr = new Thread("Hintergrund"){
        public void run(){
            try {
            while(true){

                if(frame.y < 0){
                    frame.y = 300;
                }
                frame.y -= 1;
                Thread.sleep(50);
                panel.repaint();
                }
            }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };

    Thread anim = new Thread("shipanimation"){
         public void run(){
             try {
                 while(true){
                 if(Frame.frame.animation > 7){
                     Frame.frame.animation = 0;
                 }else{
                Frame.frame.animation++;
                 }
            System.out.println(Frame.frame.animation);
                panel.repaint();
                Thread.sleep(500);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
    };
    backgr.start();
    anim.start();
    contentPane.add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

}
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? The program seems to increase the number twice, and also prints it twice, then sleeps for 500ms and then does the same again.

Edit: Thanks for your tips, so i changed the Code to:

```
public Frame() {
    aTimer = new Timer(400, this);
    aTimer.start();
    backTimer = new Timer(25, this);
    backTimer.start();
            setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel = new RenderPanel();
    setBounds(100, 100, 256*3, 276*3);
    ship.setPos((this.getWidth()/2), (this.getHeight()/4)*3);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

} 
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource() == aTimer){    
    if(Frame.frame.animation > 7){
         Frame.frame.animation = 0;
     }else{
    Frame.frame.animation++;
     }
    System.out.println(Frame.frame.animation);
    panel.repaint();
    }
    if(e.getSource() == backTimer){
        if(frame.y < 0){
            frame.y = 300;
        }
        frame.y -= 1;
        panel.repaint();
    }

}
```

But it's still the same, the timer executes everything twice and then waits the time.

Comment: Instead of using a Thread and sleep, you should be using `javax.swing.Timer`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic is right. Your current realisation is very odd. Also: You are never killing the threads you are starting, so there might be half dead thread spooking around and doing the same.

Comment: anime Thread needs a while(Thread.currentThread is not interrupted) not an infinite loop

Comment: I think there is something missing here. Can you make the Frame not static?

Comment: I dont think i can Eclipse says: can not make a static reference to the non static field frame if i do so.